# Looping Through Data Frames with Dynamic withColumn Injection

Tags: python, python-3.x, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I'm looking to create a dynamic .withColumn.

with the column "rules" being replaced by a list depending on the file being processed.

for example: File A has a column called  "Validated" that is based on a different condition to File B but has the same column name A. So can we loop through all files A-Z applying different rules for the same column in each file?

Here I am trying to validate many dataframes. Creating an EmailAddress_Validation field on each dataframe. Each data frame has a different email validation rule set. The rules are stored in a list called EmailRuleList. As we loop through each data set the corresponding rule "EmailRuleList[i]" is passed in from the list.

code below has the syntax.  Also commented out with an "#" (hash) is an example of a rule.
Interestingly if I supply the rule with out the loop (the # comment) the code works except it then obviously applies the same rule to all files.

```
i=0
for FileProcessName in FileProcessListName:
    EmailAddress_Validation = EmailRuleList[i]
    #EmailAddress_Validation = when((regexp_extract(col("EmailAddress"),EmailRegEx,0))==(col("EmailAddress")),0).otherwise(1)
    print(EmailAddress_Validation)
    print(FileProcessName)
    i=i+1
    vars()[FileProcessName] = vars()[FileProcessName].withColumn("EmailAddress_Validation", EmailAddress_Validation)
```

Error Message:  col should be Column

EmailRuleList is something like...

```
['when((regexp_extract(col("EmailAddress"),EmailRegEx,0))==(col("EmailAddress")),1).otherwise(0)',
 'when((regexp_extract(col("EmailAddress"),EmailRegEx2,0))==(col("EmailAddress")),0).otherwise(1)',
 'when((regexp_extract(col("EmailAddress"),EmailRegEx3,0))==(col("EmailAddress")),0).otherwise(1)',
 'when((regexp_extract(col("EmailAddress"),EmailRegEx4,0))==(col("EmailAddress")),0).otherwise(1)']
```

tried lots of different things but am a bit stuck

Answer (score 0):

- The error is in the last line of the for loop. The when condition that you want to check in the `.withColumn()` is actually a string (each element of `EmailRuleList` which is a string).
- Since `withColumn` expects the send argument to be a column, it is giving the error. Look at a similar error when I try to give something similar to your code (in withColumn()):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when,col

df.withColumn("check","when(col('gname')=='Ana','yes').otherwise('No')").show()
```

[image]

- To make it work, I have used `eval` function. So, using the following code wouldn't throw an error:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when,col

df.withColumn("check",eval("when(col('gname')=='Ana','yes').otherwise('No')")).show()
```

[image]

- So, modify your code to the one given below to make it work:

```
i=0
for FileProcessName in FileProcessListName:
    EmailAddress_Validation = EmailRuleList[i]
    #EmailAddress_Validation = when((regexp_extract(col("EmailAddress"),EmailRegEx,0))==(col("EmailAddress")),0).otherwise(1)
    print(EmailAddress_Validation)
    print(FileProcessName)
    i=i+1
    vars()[FileProcessName] = vars()[FileProcessName].withColumn("EmailAddress_Validation", eval(EmailAddress_Validation))
```